# Reading file content from uploaded text file

Tags: web2py

I have an uploaded file in uploads folder and i need to read the contents from it in the controller for processing it further. I have very basic knowledge of web2py and couldn't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
import os
filename = db.mytable(record_id).myfile
content = open(os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads', filename), 'rb').read()
```

UPDATE: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38012530/440323) is a somewhat simpler approach.

Comment: how do I get the filename - i am using SQLFORM.factory

Comment: This question and answer is not relevant if you are using `SQLFORM.factory`. If you are storing the file, first we need to know how you are doing that and how it is being named. You should probably create a new question and provide more detail.

Comment: My question on google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/web2py/yebach%7Csort:date/web2py/9REMIEyN-mQ/Q3LrqJrJBQAJ