# File upload at web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am using the web2py framework. 
I have uploaded txt a file via SQLFORM and the file is stored in the "upload folder", now I need to read this txt file from the controller, what is the file path I should use in the function defined in the default.py ?

```
def readthefile(uploaded_file):
    file = open(uploaded_file, "rb")
    file.read()
    ....
```

Comment: Anthony answered that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26973208/6479329

Answer (score 0):

You can do join of application directory and upload folder to build path to file.
Do something like this:

```
import os

filepath = os.path.join(request.folder, 'uploads', uploaded_file_name)
file = open(filepath, "rb")
```

> **request.folder**: the application directory. For example if the
>   application is "welcome", `request.folder` is set to the absolute path
>   "`/path/to/welcome`". In your programs, you should always use this
>   variable and the `os.path.join` function to build paths to the files you
>   need to access.

Read [request.folder](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-corer#request)

Comment: This will work, but first you need to get the `uploaded_file_name`. Also, there is an easier way using the field's `.retrieve` method, which also returns the original filename (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38012530/440323)).

Answer (score 0):

The transformed name of the uploaded file is stored in the upload field of your database table, so you need a way to query the specific record that was inserted via the `SQLFORM` submission in order to get the name of the stored file. Here is how it would look assuming you know the record ID:

```
stored_filename = db.mytable(record_id).my_upload_field
original_filename, stream = db.mytable.my_upload_field.retrieve(stored_filename)
stream.read()
```

When you pass a filename to the `.retrieve` method of an upload field, it will return a tuple containing the original filename as well as the open file object (called `stream` in the code above).